# Ruby falls back to old version after becoming root on ubuntu with rvm installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

After becoming root (with su root), ruby automatically falls back to old version which is 1.9.2-p180. After exit from root, the ruby is automatically back to newer version which is 1.9.2-p290.

rvm is installed on the system and p290 was installed with rvm. p180 was installed with apt-get.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: If root is using the system ruby then maybe you're initializing root's environment to use rvm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the root user has a different environment from your regular user, you probably want to use `rvmsudo` whenever you're using `rvm` in a root context. This command specifically preserves the version of Ruby currently in use.

Comment: rvmsudo use 1.9.2 --default with error: rvmsudo command not found.

Comment: `rvmsudo` is the same as `sudo` with the `rvm` environment preserved. You would do: `rvmsudo {command}` or in this case `rvmsudo rvm use 1.9.2 --default`

Comment: rvmsudo rvm use 1.9.2 --default did install gem bundler, as regular user (instead as a root). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use .rvmc in root of project directory  with content

```
rvm use ruby-<version>@<gemset>
```

I have for instance ruby-1.9.2-p290 installed  and I created gemset rails 311 for rail 3.1.1, so content of my .rvmc file is

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311
```

Answer (score 0):

first check if rvm is installed system wide or for a particular user. if it is installed for a particular user, you should be using the system ruby when on a root.
you can check this by type rvm while on root user

generally rvm is installed for a particular user.

You should update your system ruby if you want to use ruby 1.9.2-p290